# Facing issue while extracting data from MS Excel using Visual Basic

Tags: excel, vba

I have written below code to generate data into notepad format from MS excel using VB code.
I am getting the file in notepad but problem is that if there are multiple sheet in the excel then also I am getting a single extract. I want to get the extract of all the sheet in a diff file.

please suggest.

```
Private Declare Function GetTempPath Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetTempPathA" _
(ByVal nBufferLength As Long, ByVal lpBuffer As String) As Long

Private Const MAX_PATH As Long = 260

'~~> Change this where and how you want to save the file
Const FlName = "C:\My\excel\MyWorkbook.vbs"

Sub Sample()
    Dim tmpFile As String
    Dim MyData As String, strData() As String
    Dim entireline As String
    Dim filesize As Integer

    '~~> Create a Temp File
    tmpFile = "C:\My\excel\Sheet1.vbs"

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=tmpFile _
    , FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False

    '~~> Read the entire file in 1 Go!
    Open tmpFile For Binary As #1
    MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , MyData
    Close #1
    strData() = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)

    '~~> Get a free file handle
    filesize = FreeFile()

    '~~> Open your file
    Open FlName For Output As #filesize

    For i = LBound(strData) To UBound(strData)
        entireline = Replace(strData(i), """", "")
        '~~> Export Text
        Print #filesize, entireline
    Next i

    Close #filesize

    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub

'Function TempPath() As String
    'TempPath = String$(MAX_PATH, Chr$(0))
    'GetTempPath MAX_PATH, TempPath
    'TempPath = Replace(TempPath, Chr$(0), "")
'End Function
```

Comment: Hi All, Please suggest how can I get result in multiple sheet

Answer (score 0):

When you use the statement `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ...` then you're going to save all worksheets at once. Instead, loop through the worksheets and save each one separately...

```
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

    Sheet.SaveAs Filename:=tmpFile, FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False

    ' Open and process the file...

Next
```